# How to initialize an array which has already declared in C#?

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, initialization

I have already declared an array:

```
double[,] g_bessel = new double[2, 2];
```

And, I want to initialize it at another place:

```
{{1,2},{3,4}}
```

How can I initialize the matrix at a once and not cell by cell?

## I mean something like this:

```
g_bessel = {{1,2},{3,4}};
```

Comment: A side note: Your use of `new` keyword actually _initializes_ the array, not merely declares it. The array is _initialized_ with the default values. You can simply use `double [,] g_bessel;` and then in the _another_ place, you can use Yuri's code (as below) to _initialize_ the array.

Answer (score 2):

You must use operator "new" for initialize new array in this way.

```
   g_besse = new double[,]{{1,2},{3,4}} ;
```

This code allocates new memory for array. 
If you need reinitialize this array many times, you can create custom method for change array's values.